# PostgreSQL open connection takes too long

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I am currently developing a project using the following libs/frameworks:

- hibernate: 5.2.11.Final
- spring: 5.0.2.RELEASE
- postgresql: 9.4.1212
- mysql: 5.1.31
- spring-data-jpa: 2.0.2.RELEASE

The project should be available in both Postgres and mysql. I am also using a profiler program called "Prefix" to track possible performance issues.
I realized that all my queries on postgresql were taking longer than the ones made on mysql, so I decided to look on profiler what was the issue.
Whenever I tried to establish a new connection to the database on mysql (DriverManager.getConnection), it took something between 5~10ms, and the same connection to postgresql is taking about 200ms+.

Do you guys know what could be making driver connections on postgresql take longer than mysql?

Here is how the db is configured:

```
public DataSource dataSource() {
DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
...
dataSource.setDriverClassName(org.postgresql.Driver);
...
}

private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto", props.getHibernateJPAAutoConfig());
    if (props.getDatabaseName().equals(ProjectConstants.DATABASE_POSTGRE)) {
        properties.put("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect");
        properties.put("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys", true);
        properties.put("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults", false); //started using those properties because I read that it could make postgresql connections faster; however it did not work.

    }
    return properties;
}

public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    factory.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
    ...
    }
```

Comment: Most probably unrelated, but: why are you using such an old driver? Also: why aren't you using a connection pool?

Comment: Good question. I was using the lastest version of postgresql "42.2.1". The reason that I switched to this older version is because I was trying to check if on an older version I would get a different result (perhaps there could be a bug on the newest versions, you never know), but that was not the case. 
As for the connection pool, I don't have a good answer for you. I am kinda new in developing dbs and was not sure how to properly configure it, but I will take a look on that =).

Comment: Instead of Spring's `DriverManagerDataSource` you could use the the `ConnectionPoolDataSource` built into the Postgres JDBC driver: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/ds-cpds.html

Comment: Oh nice! I will definitely take a look on that, thank you!

Comment: You are using Spring Boot (judging from the property names) then why are you doing work to work around Spring Boot? Just include something like HikariCP (default with Spring Boot 2.0.0) and just start the application. You don't need your datasource or entity manager configuration Spring Boot takes care of that.

Comment: Actually I am not using Spring Boot, but I managed to decrease the time using c3p0 connection pool from Hibernate. thanks again for all the help =).